# Correct use of 'comprise'

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

"The application site comprises an existing care home which has 59 bedrooms and 85 registered bed spaces"

I was under the impression that 'comprise' would indicate plural, eg

"the playground comprises a slide, a climbing frame, and a swing"

and that using it singularly is incorrect, eg

"the playground comprises a slide"

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the object of comprises needs to be plural.  *Comprises* can be translated to *is comprised of*; if something is made up of only one thing, like a care home, I think you can still say *comprises*.

Consider this example:

> "His suggestion comprises the only real solution to the problem."

Comment: I think you mean *comprises* can be translated to "is composed of."

Comment: Although *composed of* is synonymous, I meant to show the alternate usage to render it as a prepositional phrase.  *Comprises* can also be stated *is comprised of*, and that is how I meant it.

Comment: I think a better example of *comprise* with singular object might be something like “Modern Texas comprises the entirety of the pre-contact Karankawa territory.”

Comment: Or, "the city of San Francisco comprises the county of San Francisco".

Comment: @DJFar: Yeah, and I'm one of those people who *hates* when folks use comprised and composed interchangeably.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to avoid annoying people who feel strongly that parts constitute a whole, and a whole comprises parts, then it would be better to say

> The application site consists of an existing care home that comprises 59 bedrooms and 85 registered bed spaces.

than to say (as in the original)

> The application site comprises an existing care home which has 59 bedrooms and 85 registered bed spaces.

Having said that, I must say that I am very sympathetic to Brian Donovan's example (in a comment above):

> Modern Texas comprises the entirety of the pre-contact Karankawa territory.

and DJ Far's further example (also in a comment):

> The city of San Francisco comprises the county of San Francisco.

I consulted a number of books on English usage, however, and only one of them addresses the question of using *comprise* in connection with one (singular) thing encompassing of another (singular) thing—although *Webster's Dictionary of American Usage* (1989) notes this example of (formally) plural-to-plural comprising in Jane Austin, *Mansfield Park* (1814):

> Three months comprised thirteen weeks.

The exception to the general, narrow focus on the (deplored) application of *comprise* in situations where *compose*, *constitute*, *consist (of)*, or *make up* are just as clear and less controversial, is in Eric Partridge, *Usage and Abusage* (1947), which provides the following discussion:

> **comprise** and **constitute**. *Comprise*, 'to constitute, to compose' is rare and , I think, to be avoided, as in 'Ten dogs comprise the pack'. Whereas *constitute* = 'to form, to make up', as in 'Reading, writing, and arithmetic ... do not in themselves constitute an education' (Lubbock), comprise = 'to include', esp. in a treatise; 'to sum up' (e.g., 'to comprise much in a short speech'); 'to comprehend or include under or in a class or denomination'; (of a thing) 'to contain as parts forming the whole; to consist of (certain specified parts)', as in 'The house comprises box-room, nine bedrooms, bath-room, etc.'; and 'to embrace as its contents, matter, or subject', as in 'The word politics ... comprises, in itself, a difficult study' (Dickens) (*The O.E.D.*)

Partridge's commentary seems to permit "Thing 1 comprises thing 2 consisting of x, y, and z" if you interpret thing 2 as being "embraced as to its contents, matter, or subject."

Still, it is remarkable that authorities from Fowler, *Modern English Usage* (1926), to Evans & Evans, *A Dictionary of Contemporary American Usage* (1957), to Follett, *Modern American Usage* (1966), to Bernstein, *The Careful Writer* (1973), to Shaw, *Dictionary of Problem Words & Expressions* (1975), to Room, *The Penguin Dictionary of Confusibles* (1979), to Copperud, *American Usage & Style: The Consensus* (1980) to Claiborne, *Saying What You Mean* (1986), to Randall, *Webster's New World Guide to Current American Usage* (1988), to *WDEU* (1989), to Wilson, *The Columbia Guide to Standard American Usage* (1993), to O'Conner, *Woe Is I* (1996), to Wallraff, *Word Court* (2000), to Bryson, *Bryson's Dictionary of Troublesome Words* (2002), to Garner, *Garner's Modern American Usage*, second edition (2003)—despite discussing whether parts can comprise a whole—have nothing to say on the precise question that the poster asks here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it with a singular element (Collins):

> verb (transitive)
>
> ```
> to include; contain
> to constitute the whole of; consist of   ⇒ **"her singing comprised the entertainment"**
> ```
>
> The use of of after comprise should be avoided: the library comprises
>   (not comprises of) 500 000 books and manuscripts